# Calling scope.$parent.function outside the directive in a controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have this function inside my directive link function:

```
scope.$parent.resetData(){
   scope.data = '';
}
```

in my html:

```
<ul ng-model="selectedObject">
  <li>{{ object.label }}</li>
</ul>
<button ng-click="resetData()">reset!</button>
<directive data={{ selectedObject.dataset }}></directive>
```

and in my app.controller

```
$scope.$watch('selectedObject', function(){
   $scope.resetData(); //this cant be used 
});
```

i cant use $scope.reset() in the controller scope, is there a way to be able to re-use that function in the simpliest way instead of doing a factory/service for this dataset?

Comment: Can you explain why you can't use `$scope.reset()` in the controller scope? I'm not following all the way.

Comment: that is supposed to be the function i made in my link directive function that i want to use in my app.controller, that doesnt work but i can use it in the template

Comment: but you can say `scope.data = ''` in the controller, right?

Comment: i cant actually, its an isolated scope for the data and i want to reset the data depending on the selectedObject so i need to watch the selectedObject to reset the scope.data

Comment: What if you fed the directive `selectedObject` instead of `selectedObject.dataset` and let it manage the reset internally, would that work? If it did it would be more encapsulated, which would be good.

Comment: its actually to much work to do right now because of what its inside already but ill give it a try!  thanks for the idea

Comment: Ok I added an answer in case a better answer doesn't come along. I know you are looking for a simpler answer. Thanks!

Comment: alright ill give it a few minutes if nothing else comes out i guess ill have to rewrite a lot of code but im pretty suure that with this i wont be needing the reset action thanks to you!

Comment: Make a copy before you tear it up :) Word from an old man!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feed the directive `selectedObject` instead of `selectedObject.dataset` and let it manage the reset internally.

It would be more encapsulated, which would be good. If changing `selectedObject` always resets the data, thinking of the directive as a component and having the logic inside makes it more self-contained. That way outside code doesn't have to worry about helping the directive do its job.

Answer (score 0):

If you insert a ctrl argument to the link function
You can talk directly to the parent controller

```
    link: function(scope, el, attr, ctrl) { 
        scope.isSmall = function(){
            return ctrl.isSmall();
        };
     }
```

At least that's how it works for me

Comment: thanks man it did worked but after that i had to face a whole new diferent things to fix

Comment: @AbdulHamid Yes that happens a lot to me to.